# what is SPI Check while uploading iOS?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apple-m1

while uploading the app from xcode 13.x it stuck to

> "Performing SPI Check.."

any idea what is this about?, added a pic for reference.

[image]

Comment: I've been facing this "Performing SPI check…" stage the last two times I uploaded to App Store Connect and I don't know what it is. It takes a very long time to finish.

Comment: same here but it got solved when I re-initiated the uploaded process

Comment: First validate the build, then upload it. First time me also faced the same issue....

Comment: @Naresh you mean if I validate the build, then SPI check time would decrement?

Answer (score 5):

`Service Provider Interface` most likely,
and I'd be guessing they are checking for usage of private APIs
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem, but it worked after retrying the upload process.

For anyone, if the issue persists try restarting the Mac or try more suggestions from this [Thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/703271)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe System Programming Interface where it checks to see if you're calling any private APIs?